# Why doesn't the "auto-create feature" in the Ftools module work on Features 2.x?

Tags: features

I've been using the [Ftools](http://drupal.org/project/ftools) module for a long time to create features more easily; this module provides a "auto-create feature" link on the features configuration page.

However, when I upgraded from Features 1.x to Features 2.x., "auto-create feature" no longer works; it simply removes everything from the .info file.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features 2.x has this functionality built in, so you don't need to use ftools anymore.  Go to the feature configuration page, click `Advanced options`, set the **Path to Generate feature module**, and then click *Generate feature*.

Comment: Don't forget to enable 'Generate features' permission for a target user